# How to place the search form in the middle of navbar and expand it in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5, search-form

I'm using Bootstrap v5.1.3 and I have added a navbar like this:

[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ1zl.png)

And here is the code for that:

```
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <form class="d-flex">
                            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Cart</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

But I need to exapnd the search form and place it at the center of navbar, so it would be looked like this:

[expected search form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fED6j.png)

So I tried adding id of to the form:

```
<form class="d-flex" id="search">
```

And added this:

```
#search{
   text-align:center;
}
```

But it does not still work out and shows the search form at the left.

So how to place this search form in the middle of navbar and expand it also a little bit in Bootstrap 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-grow-1` to make it expand...

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <form class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Cart</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/zL7fRRq6gK